# How to get DB snapshot for Rococo

Tags: parachain, rococo

Polkadot and Kusama snapshots are available here https://polkashots.io/ but I couldn't find for Rococo.

Can somebody please guide me to find DB snapshot for Rococo?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are Rococo snapshots available. Snapshots are often used by validators to recover from a fault. This does not apply to Rococo so no one wants to provide them.
Your fastest option is probably to use `--sync fast-unsafe` to create your own snapshot.

Comment: Do you mean I should add `--sync fast-unsafe` in the command to run node?

Comment: Yes, that would make it a bit faster. But it could be that it is already fast enough with normal sync.

Comment: Well don't you need to sync a collator to connect to rococo? specifically the embedded relay chain node. Perhaps these would be good to request be made available  for more rapid testing there... especially once parathreads are possible there.

Comment: The OP did not mention what they actually want to do. With the node splitting you can just use a trusted remote node instead of syncing a relay node.